# asp.net web form response csv type to zip

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, zip, response

in Page_Load web form when !IsPostBack , I run a stored procedure and the result go to DataTable.
I Do not want to write on disk. So I create a response csv type.
It works correctly.
Now how can I decrease the size of download csv file?
(When records count is 2000000 the download size is 200MB)

```
DataTable dt = GetFromSP();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + CalcCod + ".csv");
                Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                int iColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                {
                    Response.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
                    if (i < iColCount - 1)
                    {
                        Response.Write(",");
                    }
                }

                Response.Write("\n");

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < iColCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[i]))
                        {
                            Response.Write(dr[i].ToString());
                        }
                        if (i < iColCount - 1)
                        {
                            Response.Write(",");
                        }
                    }
                    Response.Write("\n");
                }

                Response.End();
```

[image]

Comment: attach a screenshot of values in csv or provide sample data! Do you want to reduce the size or compress it to zip

Comment: compress it to zip

Answer (score 0):

Look into generating an .xlsx file instead of a .csv file.  There may be libraries you can leverage, or just write your own from documentation.  Essentially the .xlsx file is a zip file containing XML.